# Python wrapper for the Help Scout API

Tags: python, parsing, api, python-2.x

I started porting an API wrapper from Java to Python for practice. I am looking for ways to improve the readability/maintainability this code.

I have done some reading about "pythonic" style and I am hoping someone could provide some feedback as to how one goes about making their code more pythonic.

All source can be found [here](//github.com/mccannm11/helpscout-api-python).

The models module is what contains the custom types that the parser creates.

```
import requests
import json
import base64
import models

class ApiClient:
    BASE_URL = "https://api.helpscout.net/v1/"
    apiKey = ""

    def getMailbox(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + ".json"
        if fields != None:      
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getItem(url, "Mailbox", 200)

    def getMailboxes(self, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes.json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url,"Mailbox", fields)

    def getFolders(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + "/folders.json"
        if fields != None:    
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "Folder", 200)

    def getConverstationsForFolders(self, mailbox_id, folder_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + "/folder/" + str(folder_id) + "conversations.json"
        if fields != None:     
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "Conversation", 200)

    def getConversationsForMailbox(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailbox/" + str(mailbox_id) + "/conversations.json"
        if fields != None :
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url)

    def getConversationForCustomerByMailbox(self, mailbox_id, customer_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + "/customers/" + str(customer_id) + "/conversations.json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "Conversation", 200)

    def getConversation(self, conversation_id, fields=None):
        url = "conversations/" + str(conversation_id) + ".json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getItem(url, "Conversation", 200)

    def getAttachmentData(self, attachment_id):
        url = "attachments/" + str(attachment_id) + "/data.json" 
        json_string = self.callServer(url, 200)
        json_obj = json.loads(json_string)
        item = json_obj["item"]
        return item["data"]

    def getCustomers(self, fields=None):
        url = "customers.json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "Customer", 200)

    def getCustomer(self, customer_id, fields=None):
        url = "customers/" + str(customer_id) + ".json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "Customer", 200)

    def getUser(self, user_id, fields=None):
        url = "users/" + str(user_id) + ".json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getItem(url, "User", 200)

    def getUsers(self, fields=None):
        url = "users.json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return self.getPage(url, "User", 200)

    def getUsersForMailbox(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
        url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + "users.json"
        if fields != None:
            url = self.setFields(url, fields)
        return getPage(url, "User", 200)

    def callServer(self, url, expected_code):
        auth =  "Basic " + self.getEncoded() 
        headers= {'Content-Type': 'application-json'
                  , 'Accept' : 'application-json'
                  , 'Authorization' : str(auth)
                  , 'Accept-Encoding' : 'gzip, deflate'
                  }
        r = requests.get(self.BASE_URL + url, headers=headers)
        self.checkStatusCode(r.status_code, expected_code)
        return r.text

    def getItem(self, url, clazz, expected_code):
        string_json = self.callServer( url, expected_code )
        return Parser.parse(json.loads(string_json)["item"], clazz)

    def getPage(self, url, clazz, expected_code):
        string_json = self.callServer(url, expected_code)
        json_obj = json.loads(string_json)
        p = Page()

        for i in json_obj:
            setattr(p, i, json_obj[i])
        return p

    def getEncoded(self):
        raw = str(self.apiKey) + ":x"
        return base64.b64encode(raw)

    def getDecoded(val):
        return base64.b64decode(val)

    def setFields(self, url, fields):
        final_str = url + "?fields="
        if (fields != None and len(fields) > 0 ):
            sep = ""
            for i in fields:
                final_str += sep + fields[i]
                sep = ","

        return final_str

    def checkStatusCode(self, code, expected):
        if code == expected:
            return
        """ @todo gotta be a better way to do this """
        if (code == 400):
            raise Exception("The request was not formatted correctly")
        elif(code == 401):
            raise Exception("Invalid Api Key")
        elif(code == 402):
            raise Exception("API Key Suspended")
        elif (code == 403):
            raise Exception("Access Denied")
        elif (code == 404):
            raise Exception("Resource Not Found")
        elif (code == 405):
            raise Exception("Invalid method Type")
        elif(code == 429):
            raise Exception("Throttle Limit Reached. Too Many requests")
        elif(code == 500):
            raise Exception("Application Error or server error")
        elif(code == 503):
            raise Exception("Service Temporarily Unavailable")
        else:
            raise Exception("API Key Suspended")


class Page:
    def __init__(self):
        self.page = None
        self.pages = None
        self.count = None
        self.items = None

class ApiException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        Exception.__init__(self,message)


class Parser:
    @staticmethod
    def parse(json, clazz):
        c = getattr(globals()["models"], clazz)()
        for i in json:
            setattr(c, i, json[i])
        return c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ApiClient:
```

If using Python 2.x, consider inheriting from `object`. It makes a couple of advanced features work.

```
    BASE_URL = "https://api.helpscout.net/v1/"
    apiKey = ""
```

Class constants, like this `apiKey`, should be in `ALL_CAPS`.

```
def setFields(self, url, fields):
```

The Python style guide recommends `lowercase_with_underscores` for method names. The name is also misleading: it suggests that you are setting a `fields` property on the object.

```
    final_str = url + "?fields="
    if (fields != None and len(fields) > 0 ):
```

You don't need those parens. It's best to check against `None` using `is not None`. As @Ichau suggested, you can actually just check `if fields:`

```
        sep = ""
        for i in fields:
```

Use `for key, value in fields.items()` to avoid having to relookup each key

```
            final_str += sep + fields[i]
            sep = ","
```

Adding strings together is not a good idea because it's not very efficient. Better to put all the pieces in a list and join it. The name `sep` is also confusing because I'd think it stands for seperator, but that's not how you are using it.

```
    return final_str

def getMailbox(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
```

There is very little point to prefixes like `get`. More pythonic would be to call this method `mailbox`.

```
    url = "mailboxes/" + str(mailbox_id) + ".json"
    if fields != None:
```

Firstly, `setFields` already handles `None` correctly. There's no point in checking for it here. Secondly, you do these two lines in pretty much every method. It'd be better to pass the fields parameter to getItem/getPage/etc and handle it consistently in all cases.

```
        url = self.setFields(url, fields)
    return self.getItem(url, "Mailbox", 200)


def getDecoded(val):
    return base64.b64decode(val)
```

You seem to be missing a `self` parameter.

```
def checkStatusCode(self, code, expected):
        if code == expected:
            return
```

I don't like the happy case bailing out like this. I'd use `pass`/`else` rather then a `return` here.

```
    """ @todo gotta be a better way to do this """
    if (code == 400):
        raise Exception("The request was not formatted correctly")
    elif(code == 401):
        raise Exception("Invalid Api Key")
    elif(code == 402):
        raise Exception("API Key Suspended")
    elif (code == 403):
        raise Exception("Access Denied")
    elif (code == 404):
        raise Exception("Resource Not Found")
    elif (code == 405):
        raise Exception("Invalid method Type")
    elif(code == 429):
        raise Exception("Throttle Limit Reached. Too Many requests")
    elif(code == 500):
        raise Exception("Application Error or server error")
    elif(code == 503):
        raise Exception("Service Temporarily Unavailable")
```

Rather then all that, have a global dict mapping numbers to strings and use that. Also, why `Exception` and not `ApiException`?

```
    else:
        raise Exception("API Key Suspended")

class Parser:
```

This doesn't really fit the definition of a parser.

```
    @staticmethod
    def parse(json, clazz):
```

Why make it a staticmethod rather than just a global function?

```
        c = getattr(globals()["models"], clazz)()
```

You can just refer to `models` here, no need to mess with globals. Furthermore instead of passing strings around, you can just the class directly and skip this lookup altogether.

```
        for i in json:
            setattr(c, i, json[i])
```

I don't like doing this. The problem is that you don't know what is in that JSON and so any attributes whatsoever can be set. I'd maintain a list of the attributes I expect and check those against the ones present.

```
        return c
```

Comment: Thank you! This is wonderful feedback. I'm working on improvements right now.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your definition of "pythonic", if you haven't already check out already [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "The Zen of Python" gives some good pragmatic guidelines and [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gives some style guidelines.

Personally, pythonic or not, I like things to be easy to read and concise, so here are a couple suggestions

```
def getFolders(self, mailbox_id, fields=None):
    # if there's no mailbox_id shouldn't this throw an Exception?
    url = "mailboxes/%s/folders.json" % mailbox_id
    if fields:
        url = self.setFields(url, fields)
    return self.getPage(url, "Folder", 200)
```

Since this doesn't depend on anything in the class and looks like a utility method, you could just move it outside of the class completely and omit `self` and you might want to check if the url is `None`

```
def setFields(url, fields):
    # checks None and length
    if not fields:
        return url
    # if speed is important, you can concatenate instead
    # return url + "?fields=" + ",".join(fields);
    return "%s?fields=%s" % (url, ",".join(fields))
```

Here's an alternative to the if/else statements to simulate `case/switch`:

```
def checkStatus(self, code, expected):
    if code == expected:
        return
    def error_codes(code):
        messages = { 
            400 : "The request was not formatted correctly",
            401 : "Invalid API Key" }
        default_message = "API Key Suspended"
        return messages.get(code, default_message)
    raise Exception(error_codes(code))
```

Comment: Using the returned status code as a key for the error dict is really nice.